# Cascade styles in React CSS module

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, css-modules, react-css-modules

In my React app I had some messed up combination of inline JS styles and CSS classes. I decided to split up everything into CSS modules that I can use this way:

`import styles from './ImageTextOption.module.css'`

And use them like JS objects. However, now styles don't cascade from parent elements (that aren't defined in the same module). I had something like `.selected  .option-text`, and even though I do have `selected` class outside, because `option-text` has changed into a unique name it doesn't match the `option-text` inside `selected` element. What is the correct approach to get it matching again, using CSS modules.

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same challenge and have found it easier at times to pass styles as props to your child components.  This is a good pattern if you are reusing the child component in different places.

[Here](https://medium.com/@ryanzec/overriding-child-element-styling-based-on-parent-with-css-modules-d4555735b85b) is an example that accomplishes the very same.

Of course if the child component is specific to the parent component and is only used once, or if the parent-child combination is specific to each other, then maybe an approach would be for them to simply share the the css import at the parent level, then pass it down to child via `className='`

Comment: This is what I feared. Isn't there any feasible way to cascade normally? Like a way where the preprocessor detects cascadings like `.selected  .option-text` and processes accordingly?

Comment: Would this be what you're looking for?: https://github.com/gajus/babel-plugin-react-css-modules#how-to-reference-multiple-css-modules   I have not used it yet, but it seems like it might get you there.  

...on a related note, I've particularly had problems cascading down styles when it comes to vendor styles (KendoUI React, Material UI, etc), that's when you have be pretty savvy with the vendor's way of theme-ing/styling and passing down styles - it get can get nightmare-ish.

Comment: Haven't tried it either. Will have a look if I can't find a better solution.

Answer (score -1):

change the import statement to :

> import './<<"PathToCss">>'

Comment: import styles from './ImageTextOption.module.css' is wrong. Change it to ```import './ImageTextOption.module.css' ```

Comment: https://codeburst.io/4-four-ways-to-style-react-components-ac6f323da822

Comment: https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/ bottomline: React itself proposes to use `.module.css` naming as preprocessor is enabled for those extensions by default.